# Right-aligned columns using the tabularx environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, arrays

I'm trying to typeset a matrix which has entries of differing widths.  However, for aesthetic reasons, I would like each of the columns of the matrix to be the same width, and I'd furthermore like them to be right-aligned.

I'm working in the tabularx environment (because of its ability to adjust column width uniformly).  However, if I compile

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\[
\left[
\begin{tabularx}{1in}{XXX}
x & 0 & y\\
0 & y & -x
\end{tabularx}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

then the columns don't have the desired justification.  I looked through the tabularx documentation and discovered that I should define a new column type.  So I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\[
\left[
\begin{tabularx}{1in}{RRR}
x & 0 & y\\
0 & y & -x
\end{tabularx}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

This produced no change in output.  What am I missing?

EDIT: The following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash }p{.075in}}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash $}p{0.075in}<{$}}

$\left[\begin{array}{PPP}
x & 0 & y\\
0 & y & -x
\end{array}\right]$    
\qquad    
$\left[\begin{array}{QQQ}
x & 0 & y\\
0 & y & -x
\end{array}\right]$

\end{document}
```

produces THIS output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you are missing mathmode in your example.
You need `\[`/`\]` around the `\left[`/`\right]`.

> This produced no change in output. What am I missing?

On my machine it produces a change! The columns are right aligned.

The `tabularx` is not really meaningful if you use `X` for ALL columns.
In this case just use `p{<width>}` columns with a normal `tabular` or `array` environment, e.g.:

```
  \newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.2in}}
  \begin{array}{PPP}
```

On my installation this gives almost the same result as your second code with the `R` column:

[image]

**Edit:**
Answer to your edited problem:

The first can be fixed with `\hbox{-x}` and the second one with `\!\!-x`.

I don't think you will avoid manual adjustments here.
However, with this small sizes the result will not look very nice, and LaTeX is normally about good typesetting quality.

Comment: Thanks for pointed out the lack of math-mode.  I corrected the minimal example.  I tried your suggestion of using array instead.  The problem is that I am under size restrictions and need my columns to be fairly narrow.  For some reason array doesn't like this, and has wrapped the {2,3} entry of the matrix.  How can I force the entire entry to be on one line, even if the {2,2} and {2,3} entries are fairly close together?

Comment: Could you please reproduce this in your minimal example.

Comment: The statement of the question has been edited to include the example.

Comment: @Kristen: Thanks, I added possible solutions for that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get what I wanted, but with a lot of manipulation, etc.